# Magento 2.3.4 and OAuth 1 oauth_problem=Consumer+key+has+expired

Tags: magento2.3, oauth, integration

I'm going crazy with OAUTH1 and Magento 2.3.4 (Ubuntu + Nginx 1.14 + PHP 7.3)

I get always

oauth_problem=Consumer+key+has+expired

My Backend configs:

1. I've configured an Integration (System -> Integrations -> Add New Integration)
2. I've set Available Api: "Orders" and "Customers"
3. I've Activate the Integration
4. I've set a Postman Test with Token Request Url, Consumer Key, Consumer Secret but I get always oauth_problem=Consumer+key+has+expired

I've also tried to:

1. (Stores -> Configuration -> Services -> oAuth) to try several values for Consumer Settings -> Expiration Period: 0, 300 (default), 1000000
2. to reactivate several time the Integration
3. to generate new Integrations
4. to erase all Integration and create New one again

Nothing!

Any ideas where I'm wrong? I've read a lots of posts about it but mosts are about all

Best Regards,
Francesco

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi All,

In Stores -> Setting Oauth -> Expiration Period I need to enter value 1000000000000 (as discussed in posst https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13961)
If I leave default value (300) I got oauth_problem=Consumer+key+has+expired

Now testing with Postman I have this error:
oauth_problem=Cannot+create+request+token+because+consumer+token+is+not+a+verifier+token

Anyone resolve it?
Best Regards,
Francesco

Comment: I am also facing same issue! anyone got to know how to resolve this?